# How to get Click Listener on dynamically created textboxes

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have received response to create `2 text boxes`, I received URL and Display Text of both views, I add them in an `ArrayList`. Now i need to add click listener on them. I have written following code.

```
for(int i=0; i<tvArrayList.size(); i++){

    TextView textView;
    textView= tvArrayList.get(i);


    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i= new Intent(MavsV2PromoActivity.this, DynamicWebView.class);
            i.putExtra("URL", URL_LINK);
            i.putExtra("VIEW_NAME",VIEW_NAME);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that, it applies the same URL value to both of the views, either I click 1st or last text view, it opens the URL of last `text view` from the list.

**TextView**

```
  ArrayList<TextView> tvArrayList= new ArrayList<TextView>();

    for(int i=0; i<linksDataList.size(); i++){


        URL_LINK= linksDataList.get(i).getLinkURL();
        VIEW_NAME= linksDataList.get(i).getName();

        TextView textView =new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(linksDataList.get(i).getName());

        if(linksDataList.size() != i) {
            textView.append(" | ");
        }

        ll_links.addView(textView);



        tvArrayList.add(textView);

    }
```

Comment: Your URL_LINK and VIEW_NAME are getting modified and will always have the value of the last item in tvArrayList.

Comment: I would suggest to create a custom TextView class by extending the TextView and app a field to store the url and view_name for that textview.

Comment: @KartikSharma a custom TextView? i bet you mean a custom class implementing `OnClickListener` interface, dont you?

Answer (score 1):

Is this not more what you need to be doing? What is "tvArrayList"? You'll need to generate the textviews in the loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<myResults.size(); i++){

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    tvArrayList.add(textView);

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i= new Intent(MavsV2PromoActivity.this, DynamicWebView.class);
            i.putExtra("URL", URL_LINK);
            i.putExtra("VIEW_NAME",VIEW_NAME);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, textViews are generated and saved  in `tvArrayList`, i am adding tvArrayList code as well in the question

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the same url for both buttons. When the first loop is finished, URL_LINK (I assume it is a class member, although capital are usually used for constants) have the last value.

You can just put the OnClickListener creation into the first loop:

```
 ArrayList<TextView> tvArrayList= new ArrayList<TextView>();

for(int i=0; i<linksDataList.size(); i++){


    String urlLink = linksDataList.get(i).getLinkURL();
    String viewName = linksDataList.get(i).getName();

    TextView textView =new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(linksDataList.get(i).getName());

    if(linksDataList.size() != i) {
        textView.append(" | ");
    }

    ll_links.addView(textView);

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i= new Intent(MavsV2PromoActivity.this, DynamicWebView.class);
            i.putExtra("URL", URL_LINK);
            i.putExtra("VIEW_NAME",VIEW_NAME);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    tvArrayList.add(textView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a field to be attached to a textView, in this case, URL_LINK and VIEW_NAME, you can always create your own TextView class by extending one.

```
public class MyCustomTextView extends TextView {

    private String urlLink; //The fields required.
    private String viewName;

    //The getter and setter for each field.
    public String getUrlLink() {
        return urlLink;
    }

    public void setUrlLink(String urlLink) {
        this.urlLink = urlLink;
    }

    public String getViewName() {
        return viewName;
    }

    public void setViewName(String viewName) {
        this.viewName = viewName;
    }

    public MyCustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyCustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyCustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

}
```

Now, instead of creating a TextView you should create the CustomTextView you just created above.

```
ArrayList<MyCustomTextView> tvArrayList= new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<linksDataList.size(); i++){


            URL_LINK= linksDataList.get(i).getLinkURL();
            VIEW_NAME= linksDataList.get(i).getName();

            MyCustomTextView textView =new MyCustomTextView(this);
            textView.setUrlLink(URL_LINK); //Set fields here
            textView.setViewName(VIEW_NAME);
            textView.setText(linksDataList.get(i).getName());

            if(linksDataList.size() != i) {
                textView.append(" | ");
            }

            ll_links.addView(textView);



            tvArrayList.add(textView);

        }
```

Whenever, you want to access the fields, just use the getters. In your case, in case when TextView is clicked.

```
for(int i=0; i<tvArrayList.size(); i++){

            final MyCustomTextView textView;
            textView= tvArrayList.get(i);


            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i= new Intent(MavsV2PromoActivity.this, DynamicWebView.class);
                    i.putExtra("URL", textView.getUrlLink());
                    i.putExtra("VIEW_NAME",textView.getViewName());
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: no, you should create a class implementing `View.OnClickListener`, thats all

Comment: If OP wants the fields only when listening for Clicks, it would be fine to implement a View.OnClickListener. I gave a more general solution from which OP can get the fields at other instances as well. Different approach, but same result.

Comment: what `"other instances"`? OP wants "url" and "view_name" to be used when user clicks the view, so simply store them as the class fields (inside custom `View.OnClickListener` class)